# Linux x86: Where is the real mode address space mapped to in protected kernel mode?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, mmu

In Linux running on an x86 platform where is the real mode address space mapped to in protected kernel mode? In kernel mode, a thread can access the kernel address space directly. The kernel is in the lower 8MB, The page table is at a certain position, etc (as describe [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html)). But where does the real mode address space go? Can it be accessed directly? For example the BIOS and BIOS addons (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(My x86-fu is a bit weak. I'll add some tags so that other people can (hopefully) correct me if I'm lying anywhere.)*

Physical addresses are the same in real and protected mode. The only difference is in how you get from an address (offset) specified in an instruction to a physical address:

- In real mode, the physical address is basically `(segment_reg << 4) + offset`.
- In protected mode, the physical address is `translate_via_page_table([segment_reg] + offset)`.

By `[segment_reg]` I mean the base address of the segment, looked up in the [Global or Local Descriptor Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table) at the offset in `segment_reg`. `translate_via_page_table()` means the address translation done via paging (if enabled).

Looking [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29#ROM_Area), it seems the BIOS ROM appears at physical addresses 0x000F0000-0x000FFFFF. To get at that memory in protected mode with paging, you would have to map it into the virtual address space somewhere by setting up correct [page table](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging) entries. Assuming 4 KB pages (the usual case), mapping the entire range should require 16 ((0xFFFFF-0xF0000+1)/4096) entries.

To see how the Linux kernel does things, you could look into how e.g. `/dev/mem`, which allows reading of arbitrary physical addresses, is implemented. The implementation is in *drivers/char/mem.c*.

The following command (from e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127830)) will dump the memory range 0xC0000-0xFFFFF (meaning it includes the video BIOS too, per the memory map linked above):

```
$ dd if=/dev/mem bs=1k skip=768 count=256 > bios
```

1024*768 = 0xC0000, and 1024*(768+256) - 1 = 0xFFFFF, which gives the expected physical memory range.

Tracing things a bit, `read_mem()` in *drivers/char/mem.c* calls `xlate_dev_mem_ptr()`, which has an x86-specific implementation in *arch/x86/mm/ioremap.c*. The `ioremap_cache()` call in that function seems to be responsible for mapping in the page if needed.

Note that BIOS routines won't work in protected mode by the way. They assume the CPU is running in real mode.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux x86 32 bits, the first `896MB` of physical RAM is mapped to a contiguous block of virtual memory starting at virtual address `0xC0000000` to `0xF7FFFFFF`. Virtual addresses from `0xF8000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF` are assigned dynamically to various parts of the physical memory, so the kernel can have a window of `128MB` mapped into any part of physical memory beyond the `896MB` limit.

The kernel itself loads at physical address 1MB and up, leaving the first MB free. This first MB is used, for instance, to have DMA buffers that ISA devices needs to be there, because they use the 8237 DMA controller, which can only be mapped to such addresses.

So, reading from virtual memory address `0xC0000000` is actually reading from physical address `0x00000000` (provided the kernel has flagged that page as present)

Comment: Can you point to a proof of this behavior in https://github.com/torvalds/linux instead of just throwing in a bunch of _believe me_ numbers ? I'm not saying you're not right. I'm just saying we're coders working with code, please, be more specific

Comment: Aha, so the BIOS would be in there some where.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was going to do an experiment with `/dev/kmem` (which is like `/dev/mem` but uses kernel virtual memory instead), but unfortunately the kernel on my machine seems to be compiled without `CONFIG_DEVKMEM`, and I'm off to bed. If `/dev/kmem` was available, then I guess a sanity check would be to read from e.g. 0xC00C0000 and seeing if you get the same data as with the `/dev/mem` example (assuming 32-bit, if details differ for 64-bit). Some definitive source would be nice too. :)

Comment: @xmojmr: I've never digged into that part of the Linux kernel. I just read books from other people who did. For example, the data about the kernel being loaded at the 1MB boundary is taken from the book LInux Kernel Internals, section 1.4 "Booting: bootsector and setup". About the 896MB limit and other fine details, review the beginning of chapter 2 of the book "Understanding the Linux virtual memory manager"

Comment: @Ulfaizer: for my students, I wrote a small device driver that gave a process access to physical memory. This was for a lab session in which they (the students) had to show a graphic map of how the memory map of a process is built by the kernel, show how two copies of the same variable are at the same virtual address in each process but in different physical addresses, etc. I have more documentation on this, but it is all in spanish. It's because of the little research I had to do to build this lab session that I know about these limits and behaviour of the kernel memory.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: I did a quick hack with a kernel module on a 32-bit VM I had lying around and some "%02X" printk's of memory values around the 0xC00C0000 range. Seems to check out! It matches the output from the `dd` command.

Comment: @Ulfalizer FYI its also described here - https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html#sec:%20Bootstrapping.